# Signalr references missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, owin, nuget-package

I have a windows service application that is used to host signalr hub but when I build it is always showing few DLL missing although I have enabled nuget package restore.

My **package.config**

```
<packages>
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.6.4" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR" version="2.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core" version="2.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS" version="2.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SelfHost" version="2.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb" version="2.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Cors" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Diagnostics" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Hosting" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.SelfHost" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />

  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

**Missing DLLs**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When this happened to me , it's Visual Studio Cache issue. just click on the missing Dll and wait for a little bit, the problem usually goes away.